# Selenium Assert error comes in intellij Idea

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
package Ecommerce;

import org.omg.CORBA.TIMEOUT;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/*This is my Code
 * www.github.com/jashangunike
 * Author-Jashandeep Singh */

public class TC03 {

    static public WebDriver driver = null;
    public String baseUrl = "http://live.guru99.com/index.php/";

    @Test
    public void TestCase3() {

        driver.navigate().to(baseUrl);

        //Click on mobile link
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='http://live.guru99.com/index.php/mobile.html']")).click();
        //Click on Add to cart
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"top\"]/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/div/div[3]/button/span/span")).click();
        // Click on Qty Box
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"shopping-cart-table\"]/tbody/tr/td[4]/input")).click();
        // Clear
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"shopping-cart-table\"]/tbody/tr/td[4]/input")).clear();
        // put 1000 units
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"shopping-cart-table\"]/tbody/tr/td[4]/input")).sendKeys("1000");
        // Click on Update button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"shopping-cart-table\"]/tbody/tr/td[4]/button/span/span")).click();

        // Verification of error message
        String ExpectedMSG = "* The maximum quantity allowed for purchase is 500. ";
        String ActualMSG = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"shopping-cart-table\"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/p")).getText();
        System.out.println("Actual message "+ ActualMSG);

        try {

            assertEquals(ExpectedMSG,ActualMSG);

        }
        catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
}

        //Verifying message after emptying the cart

        driver.findElement(By.id("empty_cart_button")).click();
        String noItemsStg = ("You have no items in your shopping cart.");
        String noItemsMsg = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='top']/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/p[1]")).getText();
        System.out.println("You have no items msg = " + noItemsMsg);

        try {

            assertEquals(noItemsStg,noItemsMsg);
        }

        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

            }
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void BeforeMethod() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver" , "H:\\software\\Selenium & Java & Components\\drivers\\chromedriverlat\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void AfterMethod() {
         driver.quit();
    }
}
```

My Second Try and catch statement  not working. Where is the problem? i.e. Verifying the empty cart . One result displayed but other one not displayed. i already bold the displayed one.

**Errors comes below after debugging the code**

*

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe" -ea
>   -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   2018.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=53638:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program
>   Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   2018.1.1\plugins\testng\lib\testng-plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\jashan\IdeaProjects\SeleniumJava\out\production\SeleniumJava;H:\selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\jashan.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-api\5.0.0\junit-jupiter-api-5.0.0.jar;C:\Users\jashan.m2\repository\org\apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.0.0\apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\jashan.m2\repository\org\opentest4j\opentest4j\1.0.0\opentest4j-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\jashan.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-commons\1.0.0\junit-platform-commons-1.0.0.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   2018.1.1\plugins\testng\lib\testng.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   2018.1.1\plugins\testng\lib\jcommander.jar" org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter -usedefaultlisteners false -socket53637
>   @w@C:\Users\jashan\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_testng.tmp
>   -temp C:\Users\jashan\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_testng.tmp [TestNG] Running:
>   C:\Users\jashan.IntelliJIdea2018.1\system\temp-testng-customsuite.xml
>   Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552522
>   (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 18144 Only local
>   connections are allowed. May 10, 2018 12:46:55 AM
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Detected dialect: OSS Actual message * The maximum quantity allowed
>   **for purchase is 500. java.lang.AssertionError: expected [* The maximum
>   quantity allowed for purchase is 500.] but found [* The maximum
>   quantity allowed for purchase is 500. ] Expected :* The maximum
>   quantity allowed for purchase is 500. Actual   :* The maximum quantity
>   allowed for purchase is 500.**       at
>   org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)    at
>   org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:494)  at
>   org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:123)   at
>   org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:176)   at
>   org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:186)   at
>   Ecommerce.TC03.TestCase3(TC03.java:50)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)   at
>   org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)     at
>   org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
>   =============================================== Default Suite Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
>   =============================================== Process finished with exit code 0

*

Comment: It looks to me like your first try block is causing your test to fail; Why do you say it is your second?

Comment: Second try catch block not working

Comment: Second try catch block not working

Answer (score 0):

Your test behaved as it should have; As you had multiple assertions within the same test, the test failed and ceased executing upon the failure of the first assertion.

You may want to look into using [SoftAsserts](http://javadox.com/org.testng/testng/6.8/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.html) in your tests if your tests include multiple assertions and you wish for all assertions to be evaluated. e.g.

```
SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();

softAssert.assertTrue(false);
softAssert.assertEquals("a", "b");

softAssert.assertAll();
```